# iOS error: cannot find the symbol when linking in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, linker-errors

I have following code in Swift in A.swift file:

```
/// **A.swift**

protocol Johnkui: class {
    var name: TruncatedView? { get  set }
}

/// typealias TruncatedView = String
class TruncatedView: UIView {

}

extension UIView {

    private struct TruncatedViewKey {
        static var navigationViewKey = "navigationViewKey"
    }

    var name: TruncatedView? {
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TruncatedViewKey.navigationViewKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
        }
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TruncatedViewKey.navigationViewKey) as? TruncatedView
        }
    }
}
```

and B.swift file has following code:

```
/// B.swift
class JJ: UIView, Johnkui {

}
```

When compiling these two files, a linking error was reported:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__TFE9SwiftTestCSo6UIViewm4nameGSqCS_13TruncatedView_", referenced from:
      __TTWC9SwiftTest2JJS_7JohnkuiS_FS1_m4nameGSqCS_13TruncatedView_ in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, when combining these two files into one, the error is gone, and I cannot find out the reason for this result, what's your explanation?